# Create or Update 1:1 record on Dynamo DB related to Cognito User through AppSync with Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, apollo-client, react-apollo, aws-appsync

I'm building React App with Amplify and Apollo.
I'd like to save user setting on Dynamo DB through AppSync. One user has one or no setting record.
For users without setting record, default setting is applied.

I tried...

- use userSub as unique key on DynamoDB
- on creating, keep returned value (id) from mutation with useState to specify id to update

I've got troubles on trying either of two.

- userSub cannot be primary key. Is there any way to update (or create if not exist) record by userSub?
- returned value from mutation is always undefined. It seems to be because of async. How do I keep it with useState?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal ID for the relationship, and add a GSI using @key on the Settings table called `byOwner`. This should give you a new query that lets you find the setting record byOwner. Here are some examples https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/key#designing-data-models-using-key

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood that I can "get records" byOwner, but I would like to "update or create if not exists" byOwner. I tried adding @key but only query added. So, I still need to know if any record exists and update or create under conditions, right? Also, I need to know the id to update, don't I ?